# how do I sum two time variable in format H-i-m in php?

Tags: php

I want to calculate total working hours of an employee for a month.The time for one session of an employee is stored in the format 'H:i:s' as as string in the database.How do I add these individual sessions to calculate total time.

Comment: Can't you convert it to seconds then sum it?

Comment: You can't really. Without a date there's no way to know if the user went over midnight while working. That miscalculation might result in huge overpayments/underpayments.

Comment: share how exactly you are storing time ? share some example ?

Answer (score 0):

The function strtotime(datetime_today) will parse to seconds relative to the difference between the current datetime and 01/01/1970

```
<?php

$datetime_ref_today = '0:00:00';

$ar_times[]='00:00:10';
$ar_times[]='00:01:30';
$ar_times[]='13:50:30';

$total_time = 0;
foreach($ar_times as $val)
{
  $total_time += strtotime($val)-strtotime($datetime_ref_today);
  echo "<br/>cumul. total_time : ".$total_time." sec";;
}

echo "<br/><br/>total_time : ".$total_time." sec";
echo "<br/>Formated total_time (H:i:s): ".gmdate("H:i:s", $total_time);
?>
```

Comment: `$total_time` is then in seconds.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
 A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.